# Scipy's fsolve alternatives?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, nonlinear-functions, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to solve numerically a system of non-linear equations:

```
def func(p):
    x, f = p
    return (math.exp(-x/O)-f,
            L - L*((1 - math.exp(-x/O))**W) - x*math.exp(-x/O))
```

and I'm currently using scipy.fsolve for it in the following way:

```
x, f = fsolve(func, (10, 0.2))
```

I'm sure my way of using fsolve is correct: it works perfectly for certain range of parameters. However, it totally fails for another (e.g., O=8, L=1.67, W=8) with the following error:

```
RuntimeWarning: The number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 600.
```

I'm sure it is well solvable -- there are (at least) matlab tools, which do it. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or is there any other solver I could try?

Thanks in advance for any hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nonlinear optimization and root-finding is unfortunately sensitive to the choice of the starting point.

```
In [19]: def func(p):
    x, f = p             
    return [np.exp(-x/O) -f, L - L*((1 - np.exp(-x/O))**W) - x*np.exp(-x/O)]
   ....: 

In [20]: O, L, W = 8, 1.67, 8

In [21]: res = fsolve(func, [1, 1.2])

In [22]: res
Out[22]: array([ 2.19804447,  0.75975782])

In [23]: func(res)
Out[23]: [-2.2204460492503131e-16, -4.4408920985006262e-15]
```

Notice that your parametrization seems redundant: <s>The position of the root does not depend on `L`, and</s> you can parameterize everything in terms of `exp(-x/O)` which will likely make it much easier to the solver.

EDIT: Define `y = exp(-x/O)`. Then your first equation tells you that the root-finding is actually one-dimensional (meaning that you can use e.g. `brentq` which is more robust). But you can use fsolve as well:

```
In [43]: ry = fsolve(lambda y: 1 - (1-y)**W + (O/L)*y*np.log(y), 0.4)

In [44]: ry
Out[44]: array([ 0.75975782])
```

Comment: Although in my case the substitution worked well, since we are at it anyways, is there a rule of thumb on how to find a better initial guess? For my problem, I actually knew the expected result, hence, I've tried to set the guess close to it. Unfortunately, it didn't really improve the root finding...

Comment: @ev-br  is there a way to change the algorithm fsolve uses? I have a case where the very same system is solved in under 2 seconds (R, mathematica), while using fsolve takes 8 seconds.

Comment: @Tom Zinger No, fsolve does not have a switcheable backend. Consider changing the solver. However, best profile the problem, to see *what* is slow. My first guess would be it's just evaluations, in which case your best bet is to speed up the target function . Anyway, consider asking a separate question with details.